# How to check if a string contains invalid filename characters in c#?

Tags: c#, string, search

I have a string and I want to check if it contains any invalid filename characters. I know I could use

```
 Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars
```

to get a array of invalid filename characters and loop through to see if the string contains any invalid char. But is there a easier and shorter expression? It is c#. So can anyone help?

Comment: Just as a reminder, keep in mind that there are other ways in which a filename can be invalid, so even if you filter out all the invalid characters, you still can't assume that you've got a legal filename. :)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of it. Could you please give me a user case by the way?

Comment: @Robin a 1000 character string might be an invalid filename. Or a filename that points to a folder that doesn't exist, or a location that exists but you don't have permissions to access.

Comment: What he said, but Windows also has certain reserved filenames that you can't use. ( `NUL`, `AUX`, `CON` and a bunch of others). The end result is that no matter what you do up front to discard "obviously" wrong filenames, the only way to *guarantee* that a filename is valid is trying to create or open the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bool containsInValidFilenameCharacters(string str) {
    return str.Any(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains)
}
```

Note that this is the same as doing

```
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
return str.Any(c => invalidChars.Contains(c));
```

But since the type signature of `Contains` matches up exactly with the parameter delegate type of `Any` we can just pass it directly and it will do an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Robin it is a part of Linq. Make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file.

Comment: @Robin since you seem to be not familiar with Linq let me clarify. Most of the entry points into Linq are implemented as [extension methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension) (not the best article but makes extension methods relatively clear). These are visible so long as the correct namespace is included. A tool like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can detect when you are using an extension method and include the correct namespace for you.